# Как сделать поиск по дате?

Tags: objective-c, coredata

Как сделать поиск по дате, формат даты 25.05.16

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `NSDate`. Создание дат по строке заданного формата:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.LL.yy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"25.05.16"];
```

Сравниваются даты методом `compare`:

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");
}
```

С этим методом под рукой поиск сделать не сложно.

Полезная ссылка: [*NSDate Class Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/).

Answer (score 0):

Так же как и поиск по любому другому полю. Через **NSPredicate**

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yy"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(@"25.05.16")
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date == %@)", date]]
```